# VSCode, Hypersnips and Context

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm struggling to make the 'context' feature work in my snippets definition. Or maybe I'm struggling to understand how it's supposed to work.

I was hoping to do something like this (pseudo code):

```
global
  function fruitOrVeg (context)
    return some stuff that gets the context that
    tells me if I'm inside 'fruit' block
endglobal

snippet eaten() "What did I eat" A
  `` if fruitOrVeg == fruit {
       rv = 'you ate some fruit'
     } else {
       rv = 'you ate some vegetables'
     }
endsnippet
```

So then in my code (javascript) I coud do this (don't get hung up on why, the example output doesn't really illustrate the reason for trying to do this)

```
eaten()
```

which would output:

```
'you ate some vegetables'
```

but if I did:

```
with (fruit) {
  eaten()
```

it would output:

```
'you ate some fruit'
```

Is this possible and if so how do I get that kind of context from VSCode?